# Notion API children nesting limit

Tags: notion-api

I'm working on HTML to Notion converter that loads simple HTML content directly to Notion using API, but I have issue with the "Nested Children" limit as per [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/patch-block-children).
It is possible to append additional child nodes using second call, but tracking back the right location is quite complicated. For example when converting structure like this:

- (1) Paragraph / DIV

  - (2) List with multiple items

    - (3) Nested list with more item

      - (4) Nested item related content (like image)

The last item (4) won't be accepted by Notion API (too deep). Adding that item in second  call requires knowing the exact ID of item (3), which can be one many of items on the list, between also many items in list (2). This makes it quite hard.

Does anyone have any suggestion (aside "flattening" the HTML source which is not ideal) how to solve this?